# What gets returned from mongoDB query if user is not found?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am building login system and want to check whether user exists in database and if passwords match. Later one works good but cant figure out first if statement.

```
        try{
               const foundUser = await User.find({"username": req.body.username});
               if(foundUser === [])   // returns false
               res.send('user not found')
               else if(foundUser[0].password === req.body.password)
               res.send('success')
               else
               res.send('invalid password')
           }catch(err){
               res.send('Something went wrong', err)
           }
```

When tested using postman i commented out everything below first line (not catch block) and just sent foundUser variable as response. The value i got is []. Now my if statement compares [] === [], returns false and triggers catch block. Why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

find will return array and findOne will return object
you can easily check with the length of an array

```
 if (foundUser.length === 0)
```

and it is going to catch block because your first statement is false and second statement is

```
 if (foundUser[0].password.....
```

foundUser is empty and you are getting first index object and comparing password

Comment: Yeah figured it out, we posted at the same moment